# Heroku with Cloudflare Domain Name Error marker in dashboard from Automated Certificate Management

Tags: ssl, heroku, cloudflare

I registered a domain over at *Godaddy* : **example.com**, then created an account with *Cloudflare* and added the Nameservers they give to *Godaddy*, after that i added my custom domains to heroku.Then I followed the steps in this guide [Configure Cloudflare and Heroku over HTTPS](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/205893698).

This guide says to set the **CNAME** for the (www and RootDomain) to the *default Heroku domain name provisioned for my app*, so I used **example.herokuapp.com** for both and marked everything to pass through cloudflare "*orange cloud*".

Now my DNS settings in Cloudflare are like so:

```
Type     Name            Value                                    TTL
CNAME    example.com     is an alias of example.herokuapp.com     Automatic
CNAME    www             is an alias of example.herokuapp.com     Automatic
```

And Heroku Dashoard

```
Domain Name                       DNS Target

(X) example.com                    example.com.herokudns.com

(X) www.example.com                www.example.com.herokudns.com
```

I got this error marker **(X)** in *herokus* dashboard with a failing tooltip popout and a message:

Automated Certificate Management has failed for the following domains:

```
| Domain | Reason | | :--- | :--- | | example.com | | | www.example.com | |
```

What am I missing why am i getting this error, my site loads and its using https from *Cloudflare*.

Should i use the DNS Target from heroku  **example.com.herokudns.com** and **www.example.com.herokudns.com** instead of **example.herokuapp.com** but they warn Cloudflare's security and speed features will not work

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/), [Web Apps Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/) or [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: It is a programing question production deployment,its not like am asking how to make marmalade jam. Many other programmers might face the same problem am one of them and Heroku's programing community for asking questions is setup here why else is their tag for. Sorry for asking for help.

Comment: @ramon22 I am interested in this question, did you end up posting it elsewhere?

Comment: of course not, but I still have the errors showing  and receiving notifications.

Comment: I'm running into the same issue. Any solution yet?